# pluck + map rxjs with Angular 8 not working?

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I have a return object from an api with a structure like this:

```
{
  status: 'ok',
  stuff: [array of objs],
  page: xyz
}
```

I'm using the "pluck" operator to just pull out the property "stuff". But, I then need to run a map operator over it and add a new property to each object in the array of stuff objects that was returned. So far, my map operator is adding the property at the end of the array (and not to each object). Wondering where I'm going wrong here.

```
this.blogsFromAPI$ = 
    this.blogService
        .getBlogs()
        .pipe(
          pluck('stuff'),
          map(st => {
            st.url = "myurl" + st.alias;
            console.log(st );
          })
        );
  }
```

Then, I want to sort the array from stuff by datetime in order of most recent. Something like this:

```
// this.blogsFromAPI$ = this.blogService.getBlogs().pipe(
    //   pluck('articles'),
    //   map(articles => articles.map(a => {
    //     // take articles array from return object, loop over them, 
    //     // construct redirect url & return a new obj with the new property
    //     a.url = "http://globalfinancialdata.com/" + a.alias;
    //     return a;
    //   }), map(art => art.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.published_at).getTime() - new Date(a.published_at).getTime())))
    // );
```

Comment: stuff is an array, you probably need to iterate over each element in order to get your wanted result

Comment: but wouldn't map be able to run the code over each element in 'stuff' and make those changes. It's for data transformation, right?

Comment: On a side note, mutating the value is a side effect and the idiomatic operate for that would be tap, not map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- RxJS's `map` function maps values in a stream
- Array's `map` function iterates over an array and maps values in the array

These are similar, but not the same thing. In this case, the value in the stream **is** an array. But it could be anything. RxJS doesn't know you want to iterate over an array.

You can turn an array into a stream and map its values via RxJS like this:

```
this.blogsFromAPI$ = this.blogService.getBlogs().pipe(
  pluck('stuff'),
  mergeMap(stuff => stuff),
  map(st => {
    st.url = "myurl" + st.alias;
    console.log(st );
    return st;
  })
);
```

Now your subscriber is getting each item from your array one at a time as a stream.
You can convert back to an array like this:

```
this.blogsFromAPI$ = this.blogService.getBlogs().pipe(
  pluck('stuff'),
  mergeMap(stuff => from(stuff).pipe(
    map((st => {
      st.url = "myurl" + st.alias;
      console.log(st );
      return st;
    }),
    toArray()
  ))
);
```

Now you're turning an array into a stream, mapping its values, and then converting back into an array. This is obviously pretty wasteful. There's no reason you can't use Array's `map` inside an RxJS stream

```
this.blogsFromAPI$ = this.blogService.getBlogs().pipe(
  pluck('stuff'),
  map(stuff => stuff.map(st => {
    st.url = "myurl" + st.alias;
    console.log(st );
    return st;
  }))
);
```

Now you're using both RxJS's `map` **and** array's `map`. Which is probably what you want.

Finally, you can merge `pluck` and `map` into a single `map` if you want this to be a bit more concise.

```
this.blogsFromAPI$ = this.blogService.getBlogs().pipe(
  map(blog => blog.stuff.map(st => {
    st.url = "myurl" + st.alias;
    console.log(st );
    return st;
  }))
);
```

Which showcases RxJS's `map` being given an object rather than an array.

---

#### Sorting

If you also want to sort your array, you can use RxJS `map` on the updated array and create a new sorted array or you can just chain array funtions

```
this.blogsFromAPI$ = this.blogService.getBlogs().pipe(
  map(res => res.articles.map(a => {
    a.url = "http://globalfinancialdata.com/" + a.alias;
    return a;
  })), // <-- I noticed a missing ')' here. Gotta keep 'em lined up!
  map(art => art.sort((a, b) => 
    new Date(b.published_at).getTime() - new Date(a.published_at).getTime())
  ))
);
```

or

```
this.blogsFromAPI$ = this.blogService.getBlogs().pipe(
  map(res => 
    res.articles.map(a => {
      a.url = "http://globalfinancialdata.com/" + a.alias;
      return a;
    }).sort((a, b) =>
      new Date(b.published_at).getTime() - new Date(a.published_at).getTime())
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: out of curiosity, I want to sort the list, but when I try to use .sort() method, I get an error under 'stuff', that says 'property stuff doesn't exist on type unknown.'

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to dereference an uninitialized variable. Can't really help beyond that without seeing what you're actually doing.

Comment: In your updated post, which line is causing the error?

Comment: the line with the .sort() function call

Comment: I updated my answer. Looks like you're just missing a `(`